# Python string.lower() not working?

Tags: python, case-insensitive

I am trying to create a case-insensitive user input choice. But what I think should be correct isn't working. This is the relevant snippet of code:

```
while True:

    search = raw_input("Choose search A or B: ")
    search = search.lower()

    if search != {'A','B'}:
        print "That was not a valid choice."

    else:
        if search == 'A':
            searchAfunction()
        if search == 'B':
            searchBfunction()
        else:
            print "Search again."
```

I want the user to be able to input 'a' or 'A'.
At the moment this is the only working solution I have is this. It doesn't seem very Pythonic?:

```
while True:

    search = raw_input("Choose search A or B: ")

    if search != {'A','a','B','b'}:
        print "That was not a valid choice."

else:
    if search in {'A','a'}:
        searchAfunction()
    if search in {'B','b'}:
        searchBfunction()
    else:
        print "Search again."
```

When I include the search = search.lower() I just get stuck in a loop of "Search again". (In the full program this allows the user to choose to search again by A or B after completing a search). Any ideas?

Comment: if `search != {'A','a','B','b'}` is wrong.

Comment: If you use `lower()` your string will be converted to lower-case. You have to compare to lower-case characters then.

Comment: `search = search.lower()` -> `search = search.upper()` and `if search != {'A','B'}:` -> `if search not in ['A','B']:` et voille.

Comment: also, you probably mean `search not in {'A','B'}` instead of `search != ['A','B']`

Comment: Also, `A` and `B` are UPPER CASE, `a` and `b` are lower case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what would `{'A', 'B'}` be anyways? Is it valid syntax?

Comment: Ah, it is a set... Never to old to learn :)

Comment: `print("A in set" if 'A' in {'A', 'B'} else "A not in set")` -> `A in set` so it could work...

Comment: @RickyA: it is a set literal, defining a set with two values. You can efficiently test if another object is a member of the set with `otherobject in setobject`.

Answer (score 3):

two issues:

1) Instead of

```
if search != {'A','B'}:
```

... use

```
if search not in {'A', 'B'}:
```

The != operator is only for comparison, not for set membership.

2) use `search.upper()` instead of `search.lower()` (or alternatively, use `'a'` instead of `'A'` in the rest of your code ...)

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

Firstly, you are converting the input to lower case with `str.lower`, but then trying to compare to upper case characters in the `if` statements.

Secondly, `search != {'A', 'B'}` should be `search not in {'A', 'B'}` instead.

Putting both together, you get `if search not in {'a', 'b'}`

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense. Don't know why it has taken me so long pouring over this to realise that .lower() of course needs lower case characters in the if statements! Thanks!

Comment: @emiden Glad to help! If one of these answers solved your problem, it would be good to accept it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to compare against lower case literals, and use the appropriate comment comparator for testing the contents of your interable
    while True:

```
    search = raw_input("Choose search A or B: ")
    search = search.lower()

    if not search in {'a','b'}:
         print "That was not a valid choice."

    else:
         if search == 'a':
            searchAfunction()
         if search == 'b':
            searchBfunction()
         else:
            print "Search again."
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't realise that .lower() meant I needed to use lower case literals, it is so obvious!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things wrong with your code:

- First you change your `search` variable to lower case, but then do all of your comparisions to upper case letters. Of course those will fail.

Try this instead:

```
search = search.upper()
```

- Second, your `!=` statement is wrong. Here you are comparing if the input is not equal to `{'A', 'B'}`.

Instead, you want to compare that the input is part of the list:

```
if search not in ['A','B']:
```